PDF in Private files cannot display inside the browser
I have drupal 9 webform and files element (private file system), if i access the file its always downloaded.
I've add header Content-Disposition: Inline in the nginx conf
# Handle PDFs to display inline
location ~* \.pdf$ {
    add_header Content-Type application/pdf;
    add_header Content-Disposition "inline; filename=\"$uri\"";
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
}

# Private files handled by Drupal
location /system/files/webform/ {
    internal;
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
}

# Custom handling for PDFs in private files
location ~* ^/system/files/webform/.+\.pdf$ {
    types { application/pdf pdf; }
    add_header Content-Type application/pdf;
    add_header Content-Disposition "inline; filename=\"$uri\"";
    try_files $uri =404;
}

Unfortunately the pdf still cannot open in the browser, its always downloaded.
I check in the Browser Header content Content-Disposition valeu is attachment.
But when i try to direct access via php it's work.
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="example.pdf"');
readfile('/system/files/webform/example.pdf');

Anyone can assist me how to make pdf in private files can display in the browser, so I can display via pdf.js.
Thank you for help.
